# Alternate IC to 9500A

Tags: usb, ethernet, microchip

I want two build a USB to ethernet adapter and was looking around for an IC to do it. It looks like the 9500a from microchip seems to be the popular one. All I'm doing is making a adapter so that I can hook up to the internet through USB. I have never used an Ethernet bridge before so this is all new to me. Any alternate ICs would be appreciated and if it included built-in drivers as well that would be great too.

Comment: Judging by your level of questions, it does not look that you have sufficient qualifications to make this device. There are plenty of "alternatives", from RealTek, ASIX, etc. But both ends of interface require skills in high-frequency design. The ready-to-go USB-to-Ethernet adapters are sold for $10 on Amazon, Go buy one.

Comment: Ouch! You are probably right, I do not but I like to learn by doing. I don't mind going through the trouble of using my copy of altium in learning this kind of high frequency design work. I never had to do anything more complicated than implementing differential pairs in designs for USB. Guess you don't like the curious types of people ; ) Since you have the qualifications, can you steer me in the way of how I can get these qualifications? Because buying an adapter is an answer I will refuse to accept.

Comment: Also thanks for at least mentioning other companies. I think I will try out the AX88772 as this looks to be like exactly what I needed. In case anyone in the future who is looking to do the same, here is the link: https://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=ProductList&PLine=71&PSeries=101

Comment: Joe, If you have Altium and are willing to learn modern electronics, companies offer evaluation boards, schematic files, sample PCB layout files. Not sure about ASIX, but LAN9500A does offer the set of files and BOM recommendations. So for $100-$150 (prototype PCB) and several weeks of your time you will have the device. Of course you might need a protocol analyzer and a high-speed scope to make sure that eye diagrams on both ends are in compliance. If you just assemble a sample board and it is lucky to work, I am still not sure how you would present this as an achievement on your resume.